# Why does my XML parser writes "°C" as "&#176;C" in a newly created file?

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, lxml, elementtree

I'm using the Etree parser to edit an xml based config file. I'm able to read, find and edit the text I want to change. But when I write the whole data to a new file, the "°C" is written as `"&#176;C"`. I would like that to remain as is, i.e. "°C". Could somebody explain why the parser replaces it like this?

Example:
Original line: `<parameter name="Temperature" Units=°C>30</parameter>`

(Run python script, find "30" and set it to "200". Write the line again to a new file)

Edited line:   `<parameter name="Temperature" Units=&#176;C>200</parameter>`

Could somebody help understand this?

Comment: Yes. The quote before `C` is not valid XML when it is not paired, so it's being escaped by encoding it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks!
Is there a way to correctly execute what is intended?

Comment: No, because without the closing `"`, it's not valid XML. Your XML parser will not write invalid XML. You can write it yourself by using a text editor like Notepad or from your code by handling the file as plain text instead of XML.

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for taking the time. I'm a bit confused, could you explain which quote is unpaired? `"Temperature"` is paired, and there are no other unpaired quotes, or maybe I'm missing something? Thanks again, really appreciate your help

Comment: @Brownie `Units=°C` should be `Units="°C"` or it isn't valid XML.

Comment: @KenWhite That's a degree symbol. It's missing both quotes.

Comment: @Forensic_07: Yes, you're absolutely right. My eyes must be tired. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite, I understand. I checked my file, and indeed it contains `"°C"`. So it was indeed a typo that led to my misunderstanding. Thanks for correcting, appreciate you.
@Forensic_07, encoding='utf-8' worked like a charm. Many thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://lxml.de/parsing.html), `etree.tostring()` outputs ASCII-encoded strings by default, where the `°` symbol cannot be represented except as an entity. To specify unicode output, use the `encoding` parameter.

```
In [12]: string = '<parameter name="Temperature" Units="°C">30</parameter>'

In [13]: root = etree.fromstring(string)

In [14]: etree.tostring(root)
Out[14]: b'<parameter name="Temperature" Units="&#176;C">30</parameter>'

In [15]: etree.tostring(root, encoding="unicode")
Out[15]: '<parameter name="Temperature" Units="°C">30</parameter>'
```